# What happens to UV Tangents when using Custom Normals?

Tags: uv, shaders, normals, normal-map

Tangent Normal mapping is done with the mesh Normals and UV Tangents. For it to work, these are supposed to be consistent with those used when baking, and orthogonal to each other. When you set Custom Normals on a mesh (such as with the Normal Edit modifier, data transfer modifier, etc) the Normal changes. If the Tangent did not also change, then you could not properly use Normal Maps.

If you view the output of the Tangent node set to UV Map, you can see that it changes when enabling a Custom Normal:
[image]
(Note also that this GIF seems to be showing a bug. When the modifier is disabled, the tangents don't always go back to what they were. There's some other states happening. But this only happens in the viewport, and not on render. And not if the modifier is applied.)

My question is, what exactly is happening to the Tangents when I change the Normal? What's the pipeline? Is the Custom Normal influencing the Tangent calculations on a mesh level? Or is some vector math done on the shader level?

I've done some experiments with creating special tangent normal maps that use the Custom Normal. But the changed Tangents don't seem to behave quite right. For example, if I have a Normal Map baked to Object A, and then I transfer its Normals to Object B and use the same Normal Map on it, the result is very different even when the Normals are the same (transfer can distort them, but its a bigger difference than that.) If I compute my own UV tangents in geometry nodes and transfer those and use them instead (require custom normal map node) everything behaves correctly. So the weak link is whatever is happening to the UV tangents when you use a Custom Normal.

Comment: As far as I can tell, normal and tangent aren't actually ortho even with regular normals.  The tangent is somehow smoothed out, when theoretically it should be constant or nearly constant per triangle.  In my own normal map nodes, I fix the tangent, and it works fine; but fixing the tangent breaks the anisotropic BSDF, so I think that's where the weird tangent smoothing comes into play.  Blender doesn't really do normal map bakes/reads correctly anyways, it doesn't use an orthonormal space for them.

Comment: Interesting. My impression is they are orthogonal before being interpolated. Both start off as Face data and then are switched to Point/Vertex.

Comment: That's the thing though. The true UV tangent cannot be represented as point data; it changes discontinuously over (triangulated) edges.  We could make a true, face-corner UV tangent via GN these days.  For normal maps, we can use any kind of tangent we want, provided it remains stable through deformation (but Blender's does not), and provided we use the same tangent to bake and to read.  For anisotropy, the true UV tangent often means discontinuous anisotropy.  But Blender's implementation introduces discontinuity across a UV sphere's UV seam (where the true UV tangent is *not* discontinuous.)

Comment: Right. In my case, I'm trying to keep things consistent for export to game engines. I believe they use Mikktspace standards. I have models that use both custom vertex normals and normal maps, and I need things to be consistent in blender and in Unreal/Unity. So this question is to understand what Blender is doing, and I'm also trying to find out if the others are doing something similar. When custom normals aren't involved, the normal mapping seems consistent at least. So if blender is doing some strange things with tangents, the engines either do the same or the difference is too small to see

Comment: The first thing I'd try for matching Unity would be that true, face-corner tangent, made with GN from position lookups from UV with miniscule offsets.  However, it might be easiest to just not use custom normals: bake them into your normal map; use split edges for split custom normals.